# Getting usable dates from Axes.get_xlim() in a pandas time series plot

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to get the xlimits of a plot as a python datetime object from a time series plot created with pandas.  Using `ax.get_xlim()` returns the axis limits as a `numpy.float64`, and I can't figure out how to convert the numbers to a usable datetime.

```py
import pandas 
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from numpy.random import randn

ts = pandas.Series(randn(10000), index=pandas.date_range('1/1/2000',
    periods=10000, freq='H')) 
ts.plot()
ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim(datetime(2000,1,1))
d1, d2 = ax.get_xlim()
print "%s(%s) to %s(%s)" % (d1, type(d1), d2, type(d2))

print "Using matplotlib: %s" % dates.num2date(d1)
print "Using datetime: %s" % datetime.fromtimestamp(d1)
```

which returns:

```
262968.0 (<type 'numpy.float64'>) to 272967.0 (<type 'numpy.float64'>)
Using matplotlib: 0720-12-25 00:00:00+00:00
Using datetime: 1970-01-03 19:02:48
```

According to the [pandas timeseries docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html), pandas uses the numpy.datetime64 dtype.  I'm using pandas version '0.9.0'.

I am using `get_xlim()` instead directly accessing the pandas series because I am using the  `xlim_changed` callback to do other things when the user moves around in the plot area.

### Hack to get usable values

For the above example, the limits are returned in *hours* since the Epoch.  So I can convert to *seconds* since the Epoch and use `time.gmtime()` to get somewhere usable, but this still doesn't feel right.

```py
In [66]: d1, d2 = ax.get_xlim()

In [67]: time.gmtime(d1*60*60)
Out[67]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# First convert to pandas Period
period = pandas.tseries.period.Period(ordinal=int(d1), freq=ax.freq)
# Then convert to pandas timestamp
ts = period.to_timestamp()
# Then convert to date object
dt = ts.to_datetime()
```

Answer (score 9):

The current behavior of [matplotlib.dates](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html):

> datetime objects are converted to floating point numbers which represent time in days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1. For example, 0001-01-01, 06:00 is 1.25, not 0.25. The helper functions date2num(), num2date() and drange() are used to facilitate easy conversion to and from datetime and numeric ranges.

pandas.tseries.converter.PandasAutoDateFormatter() seems to build on this, so:

```
x = pandas.date_range(start='01/01/2000', end='01/02/2000')
plt.plot(x, x)
matplotlib.dates.num2date(plt.gca().get_xlim()[0])
```

gives:

```
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x7ff73a60f290>)
```