# Matplotlib: Time axes and limits

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have a matplotlib plot for which the x data is a Pandas DateTimeIndex.

The user can zoom the x-axis using the scroll wheel.  The limits are recalculated like this:

```
limits = ax.get_xlim()
span = limits[1] - limits[0]
pos = (1 - (limits[1] - evt.xdata) / span)
if evt.button == 'up':
    limits = ( limits[0] + span / 1.3 / 2 * pos,
               limits[1] - span / 1.3 / 2 * (1 - pos) )
elif evt.button == 'down':
    limits = ( limits[0] - span / 1.3 / 2 * pos,
               limits[1] + span / 1.3 / 2 * (1 - pos) )
```

This works and zooms the x-axis in or out on the point where the scroll event happened.  Now I'm trying to recalculate the y-axis limits to zoom to the data displayed but can't figure out how the x-axis data and the x-limits relate to each other:

```
lines = ax.get_lines()
y_lim = np.inf, -np.inf
for line in lines:
    xd = line.get_xdata()
    yd = line.get_ydata()
    y_displayed = yd[((xd > limits[0]) & (xd < limits[1]))]
    y_lim = min(np.min(y_displayed), y_lim[0]), max(np.max(y_displayed), y_lim[1])
ax.set_ylim(y_lim)
```

This fails with the message `TypeError: Invalid type promotion`.

As far as I can make out, the x-data is being stored as `numpy.datetime64` but matplotlib returns the limits as a float which represents the number of days since `0001-01-01 00:00` plus 1.  How do I get this into some form I can compare with an array of `datetime64`?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, as soon as I posted the question I figured it out:

```
from matplotlib.dates import num2date

limits = (np.datetime64(num2date(limits[0])), np.datetime64(num2date(limits[1])))
```

Comment: Do you think this is in any way useful for anyone except yourself? The question is not even complete and it is totally unclear why this line of code solves the problem (just in case someone actually understands the problem).

Comment: Well, it took me a very puzzled hour or so to figure out the different date formats involved and if someone else is going to try to manipulate the limits of matplotlib time axes then yes, I think it would be helpful to find this.

Comment: Is the question how to set the limits of axes? I would guess that this is already sufficiently answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29614350/4124317) but if you think that it's not, it would be much more useful to add an answer to that question instead of this one here, which is really hard to understand.